# ruby Argument Error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby

Hi All I am new to ruby and I am trying to implement the alogrithm to find the greatest 
common divisor using a stack:

Here is my code:

```
def d8(a,b)
  return a if (a==b)
  s = Stack.new
  s.push(b)
  s.push(a)

  c1 = s.pop(a)
  c2 = s.pop(b)

  while c1!=c2
    if s.count>0
      c1 = s.pop(c1)
      c2 = s.pop(c2)
    end

    if c1== c2
      return c1
    elsif c1>c2
      c1 = c1-c2
      s.push(c2)
      s.push(c1)
    else
      c2 = c2 -c1
      s.push(c2)
      s.push(c1)
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

However, I keep getting a Argument Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from line 7

Comment: And which one is line 7?

Comment: Where does your `Stack` class come from? And what is its source?

Answer (score 3):

`Stack#pop` method probably takes no arguments, so it should be:

```
c1 = s.pop
c2 = s.pop
```

Comment: `[0, 8, 15].pop(2)` yields `[8, 15]`.

Comment: @undur_gongor right. But it's `Stack#pop` instead of `Array#pop`, I asked the OP about its implementation.

Comment: You are right. I was mislead the same way as you. +1.

Comment: +1 Also, the fact that the error indicated (1 for 0) means that it takes no arguments and the user is trying to pass it one.