# Using stack to find the greatest common divisor

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement an alogorithm to find the greatest common divisor using a stack: I am unable to formulate the correct answer based on my logic below. Please help. Here is my code:

```
def d8(a,b)
if (a==b)
    return a 
end
s = Stack.new
s.push(b)
s.push(a)

c1 = s.pop
c2 = s.pop

while c1!=c2
    if s.count>0
        c1 = s.pop
        c2 = s.pop
    end

    if c1== c2
        return c1
    elsif c1>c2
        c1 = c1-c2
        s.push(c2)
        s.push(c1)
    else
        c2 = c2 -c1
        s.push(c2)
        s.push(c1)
    end
end
    return nil
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178033/ruby-argument-error-wrong-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 3):

GCD cannot be `nil`. Two integers always have a GCD. So the logic in the function is already incorrect just because under some condition it has a `return nil`.

Looking at this `return nil` condition, it is happening when `c1 == c2` (it will exit the `while` loop). At the same time, inside the `while` loop, you return a value `if c1 == c2`. These two cases are in logical contradiction. In other words, you are exiting the `while` loop on the `c1 == c2` condition and treating that condition as invalid before your `if c1 == c2` condition can trigger and treat the condition as valid and return the correct answer.

Simplifying the logic a little, you get:

```
def d8(a,b)
  return a if a == b   # Just a simpler way of doing a small if statement

  s = Stack.new    # "Stack" must be a gem, not std Ruby; "Array" will work here
  s.push(b)
  s.push(a)

  #c1 = s.pop       # These two statements aren't really needed because of the first
  #c2 = s.pop       #  "if" condition in the while loop

  while c1 != c2
    if s.count > 0
      c1 = s.pop
      c2 = s.pop
    end

    # if c1 == c2 isn't needed because the `while` condition takes care of it
    if c1 > c2
      c1 = c1 - c2
    else
      c2 = c2 - c1
    end

    # These pushes are the same at the end of both if conditions, so they 
    # can be pulled out
    s.push(c2)
    s.push(c1)
  end

  return c1   # This return occurs when c1 == c2
end
```

This will work, but it becomes more obvious that the use of a stack is superfluous and serves no purpose at all in the algorithm. `s.count > 0` will always be `true`, and you are popping variables off right after you push them (basically a no-op). So this is equivalent to:

```
def d8(a,b)
  return a if a == b

  c1 = a
  c2 = b

  while c1 != c2
    if c1 > c2
      c1 = c1 - c2
    else
      c2 = c2 - c1
    end
  end

  return c1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code for it would be

```java
public static int gcd (int p, int q) {
        StackGeneric<Integer> stack = new StackGeneric<Integer>();
        int temp;

        stack.push(p);
        stack.push(q);

        while (true) {
            q = stack.pop();
            p = stack.pop();
            if (q == 0) {
                break;
            }
            temp = q;
            q = p % q;
            p = temp;
            stack.push(p);
            stack.push(q);
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Replace the function call in recursive solution with the while loop and iterate it till the second argument becomes 0, as it happens with the recursive function call

```
    public static int gcd (int p, int q) {
        if (q == 0) {
            return p;
        }
        return gcd(q, p % q);
    }
```